# C# screen scraping processing a login control

Tags: screen-scraping

I am trying to login to a website using screen scraping and I am having difficulties.

```
    HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(uri);
    req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0; WOW64; SLCC1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; InfoPath.2; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; MS-RTC LM 8)";
    req.KeepAlive = false;
    req.Proxy = new WebProxy(IPAddress,PORT);
    req.Method = "POST";
    req.Host = host;
    req.Referer = referer;
    req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    req.ContentLength = postBytes.Length;

    StreamWriter requestwriter = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream(), System.Text.Encoding.ASCII);
    requestwriter.Write(postData);
    requestwriter.Close();

    try
    {
        using (HttpWebResponse res = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse())
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                sid = sr.ReadToEnd().Trim();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (WebException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(uri.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }

    return sid;
}
```

All that I get back is the login form, it is never logging me in. Any ideas? this has been asked before, can some one help me with this...i'm stuck with the same problem

Comment: What website do you try to log in and what kind of error do you get?

Comment: @Mike i'm not getting any error, i'm tryig to log in to google plus, even if i try this with a normal website which doesnt do the authentication like google does, it always returns log in form..there is something related to cookies here..i think i need to send cookies data with the request. i'm not sure how to do that...request.cookiesContainer...i dont knw how do i send my cookies with this method

Comment: created a new cookie and set the domain name, cookie value and cookie name and then added this cookie to cookie to container and sent it along with request  Cookie cookie= new Cookie("SESSee201d4242c83ea2671330cdceee4623", "52cmo3gnvpd5h06sevgaf8c0f3");
            cookie.Domain = "SESSee201d4242c83ea2671330cdceee4623";
            
            req.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
            
            req.CookieContainer.Add(cookie);

Comment: yep...even if i dont give this value in cookie object it works  tring postData = string.Format("name=Username&pass=Password&remember_me=1&form_build_id=form-b2ab9ad4c205becd8c268e6dd782273c&form_id=user_login&op=Go"); this line along with cookie object with domain value gets me thru login..